# Design pattern to add a record

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, http

I will be adding a record with very little user required information, and from a UX prospective, don't wish to direct the user to a blank "edit" page.

Instead, the user will click something, and a dialog requesting the minimum information will be presented, and upon a successful submission, the record will be displayed allowing them to use inline editing should they wish to modify.

What is the recommended design pattern to add the record?  For instance:

Option

1. Present the dialog, user fills in the data and clicks "submit", the data is client side validated, and:
2. Use JavaScript to submit the form.
3. Server validates and either internally redirects to the page displaying the newly added record, or redisplays the previous page displaying the errors.

Option 2

1. Present the dialog, user fills in the data and clicks "submit", the data is client side validated, and:
2. Send data to the server via ajax post request.
3. Server validates and either responds with errors or the PK of the added record.
4. If successful, use JavaScript to redirect to the page with the PK to display the newly added record, else display the errors.

Option 3.  ???

Please provide reasons why one patter is better than another.

Comment: can't resist...do a number 2. Get the client to do as much grunt work as possible and then escape input on DB. JS can then redirect based on returned insertId as a boolean or value, i.e. if (insertId) redirect();

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a slightly modified version of option 2.
Once the validation in the server is successful, the record is inserted and the client gets the primary key of the newly created record, with javascript close the dialog (or modal) and add the relevant information of that record in the main page, this will let you avoid redirecting to another page.

Cheers